# UEFI secure boot anti-rollback

Tags: uefi, replay-detection

I haven't seen any seen mechanism by which UEFI can detect the most recent update to a binary from being swapped out for an older binary that was signed with the same key as the up-to-date binary. Google's vboot is the only PC firmware I know of that uses anti-downgrade counters. Does the UEFI specification specify a way to thwart rollback attacks on the boot payload(s), such as the Windows bootloader, the Windows kernel, GRUB2, and Linux kernel images?

Update: UEFI does offer authenticated variables that use incorporate a timestamp or a monotonic counter in update verification to prevent rewriting the variable to an older value, but I don't know if this is used to thwart rollback attempts on the boot payload(s).

Answer (score 1):

UEFI of what ?

Generally, there was no such specification initially.

The latest UEFI specs can be found [here](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_8_final.pdf).

Some manufacturers use something called "Secure Rollback Prevention”. If enabled, it prevents any downgrade.

For example, Lenovo Thinkserver series implemented this in order to prevent people using security-flawed versions. For specific models, the BIOS cannot be downgraded to a level lower than the version listed once the BIOS is at that level or higher.

You will have to see if your UEFI has such a feature, but note that even if there is one, it may be bypass-able.

Since something like [this](https://gsec.hitb.org/materials/sg2019/D2%20-%20Bypassing%20a%20Hardware-Based%20Trusted%20Boot%20Through%20x86%20CPU%20Microcode%20Downgrade%20-%20Alexander%20Ermolov.pdf) is possible, a forced downgrade even with an option to protect against it may be trivial to accomplish.

Comment: Not the firmware. The bootloaders on the EFI system partition.